# Angularjs - How to reload only child state without reload parent

Tags: angularjs, parent-child, state, parent, reload

I'm having trouble with reload a state in angularjs. I only want to reload the child state only but when I call $state.reload(); it also reload the parent state which contain a left menu bar (if it is collapse it will expand again and I don't want this behaviour). How do I correcty reload a child state in angularjs?

Comment: can u provide a link ??

Comment: better question is why do you want to reload *any* state? You simply need to render new content